# Getting error while installing cordova using the command "npm install -g cordova"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

```
D:\Ionic\IonicDemoApp>npm install -g cordova
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
```

node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"

```
npm ERR! node v6.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.3
npm ERR! file C:\Users\amit_sharma78\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\glob\7.1.1\packag
```

e\package.json

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\amit_sharma78\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\glob\7.1.1\packa
```

ge\package.json

```
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Ionic\IonicDemoApp\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Please help if anyone have any idea.

Comment: are you trying to installing inside  the ionic project locatated in  D drive?

Comment: It could be installed from anywhere right? If no, should I try from npm location or from somewhere else?

Comment: i think we need to install on default location which shows after opening command prompt....just do one thing open ut cmd and excecute "cordova --v " and tell me what u seeing